# Nvidia-driver not working on ubuntu 20.04 with 5.15.0-051500rc6 kernel

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I have been trying to find the solution for this but I am stuck because I don't have enough time now.
I have reinstall my ubuntu 20.04, and the Nvidia x Server Settings worked, but the network adapter could not been seen by the os. I updated my kernel and now I have the 5.15.0-051500rc6-generic kernel, network adapter is working but I am in the same situation with Nvidia x Server Settings as I was before the reinstall of the os.

I open  Nvidia x Server Settings and I see nothing as in the first photo.
I have tried to type nvidia-smi in and also the answer is in the second photo.
What can I do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is that Nvidia drivers don't work with the Release Candidate kernel version.

What can you do?

1. Fix network problem with an older kernel.
2. Stay with open source Nvidia drivers.
3. Try to patch the proprietary driver to build with the new kernel if this is possible. There is an open source part that is built using `dkms`.

Comment: how can I do that, the Nvidia drivers, should I go to the software updates and change it from there?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How can you do what?

Comment: There is no fast solution to this.  You will only be able to solve this with enough time.  Either you will need to get a network driver backported to a kernel nvidia supports or you will have to check the dkms logs and correct the error preventing the nvidia driver from compiling, or you will have to wait for nvidia to release support for a new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

there is a more pragmatic solution, use the older kernel with nvidia support und use a cheap usb network dongle as interim solution

you can be sure, the nvidia graphic driver will get an update in the future

have fun,
Frank